# Reading Recursive Function out of Range Error with Vector

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm currently trying to make a function that reads a function string (for example something like : "6x^2" so to do that I created this function that recieves a string which is input, pos which is the position of the string or the recursive function depending on how many times it ran for and a vector so that it can return it once its done (then sort it via sstream) but I'm getting an out of range error on this. I added a breakpoint but that didn't really help it, heres the code:

```
vector<int> Recurofnum(const string& in, int pos, vector<int>& d) {
    if (pos == 0) { 
        // if first time
        if (isdigit(in.at(0))) { d.at(0) = in.at(0); posafterrecur++; pos++; Recurofnum(in, pos, d); }
        // ^ if first letter is a number do it over again by adding 1 to pos and calling recurofnum again
        else { d.at(0) = 1; posafterrecur++; return d; } 
        // ^if not the default is 1 for the first and only number in the vector
    }
    else // if not first time
    {
        if (isdigit(in.at(pos))) {
            // ^ if digit at current position
            if (pos == (in.size() - 1)) { return d; } // breakpoint
            else { d.at(pos) = in.at(pos); pos++; posafterrecur++; Recurofnum(in, pos, d); }
            /* ^ if first condition is true set the string's current position number to the vector
            and  call the function again to check for next position */
        }
        else { posafterrecur++; return d; } // if not return the vector
    }
    posafterrecur++;
}
```

Main is this:

```
int main() {

    string in;
    cin >> in;
    vector<int> y, b;
    y = Recurofnum(in, 0, b);
    for (const auto& i : y) { cout << y.at(i); }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Ive checked if its the sorting algorithm by simply giving it a defined vector then sort it into an int and out it, it worked perfect.

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *but I'm getting an out of range error on this* -- Unless this was all that was stated, aren't those errors supposed to tell you what value you used and what the upper limit is?  If so, then why is it difficult to debug, given this information?

Comment: This is the error its giving me https://i.imgur.com/aN4DrQO.png, its not much to go off of.

Comment: Look at the call stack.  You will see the function you wrote, and the line of code  that causes the issue.  Just see what the value being used as an index is.

Comment: @Wintér you do not check if pos is in range of d

Comment: d is empty when you access pos of d in `d.at(pos) = in.at(pos)`. you should assign some space for d in constructor or using resize.

Comment: so d.resize(1) for the first slot and d.resize(d.size() + 1) every time I do the function?

Comment: Okay so this is my problem now: https://i.imgur.com/RUJ9lln.png any help? I changed it so I resize +1 every time it runs and it doens't give me an out of range error

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in `push_back`?

Comment: I fixed it all, thanks for your help on the resizing  @abdullah and the problem with the pointers was that I wasn't returning anything after the if and else statements allthough I'm not sure why it would even get there since it will always path to a return since the else always applies and the if always applies, a minute ago it was outputting ASCII so I had to add -'0' to every operation of insertion (or define a function but thats waste of memory) thanks everyone!